# Why can we not expand $(a+b)^n$ directly when $n$ is a fractional or negative index?

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

We know the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ when $n$ is a fractional index or negative index. Why can we not expand $(a+b)^n$ directly when $n$ is a fractional or negative index? Instead of expanding directly we first take '$a$' common and write it as $a^n(1+b/a)^n$ and then we expand $(1+b/a)^n$ and multiply with $a^n$. It is written in my textbook that when $n$ is a fractional or negative index '$a$' must be equal to $1$ in $(a+b)^n$. But the result is same if we expand $(a+b)^n$ directly when $n$ is a fractional or negative index or first expand $(1+b/a)^n$ and then multiply $a^n$. I expanded $(a+x)^n$ by Taylor theorem also, the result is same. Then why can we not use binomial theorem to expand $(a+b)^n$ directly when $n$ is a fractional or negative index?

Comment: Perhaps you could illustrate what you mean, for example by expanding $(7+2)^{-1/2}$ directly using a binomial expansion rather than using $7 ^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac27 \right)^{-1/2}$

Comment: Do you mean why you cannot use the formula $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a^{n-k} b^k$? This formula only holds for $n$ being an integer and simply does not make sense for non-integer $n$.

Comment: The negative binomial theorem (Taylor series by another name) is a generalisation of the binomial theorem to fractional or negative $n$. You can use the negative binomial theorem to when $n$ is a positive integer, but you cannot do the reverse as Winther has mentioned.

Comment: Expanding $(a+b)^n$ directly may cause some convergence problem, especially when $a<b$ the expansion $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nkb^ka^{n-k}$$ will not converge

Answer (score 1):

You can, in a way. The generalized binomial theorem affords a definition of $\binom{n}{k}$, for $n\in\Bbb C$ and integer $k\ge0$, such that$$(1+b/a)^n=\sum_{k\ge0}\binom{n}{k}(b/a)^k,$$or equivalently$$(a+b)^n=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k,$$provided $|a|>|b|$. Note this modulus requirement prevents us exchanging $a,\,b$ on the RHS, even though the LHS is symmetric. (Another issue with exchanging the exponents is that $\binom{n}{k},\,\binom{n}{n-k}$ are in general no longer both defined, let alone equal, unless e make sure to write the definition of binomial coefficients in terms of Gamma functions rather than factorials & Pochhammer symbols.) Note also that our summing over all non-negative integers $k$ also holds when $n$ is a non-negative integer, because in that case any $k>n$ yields $\binom{n}{k}=0$. This case also lets us drop the constraint $|a|>|b|$ altogether, so its presence when $n$ isn't a non-negative integer is very important.